# Drupal 7 menu translation using feature

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n, features

What I am trying to achieve is I have a drupal site which is basically in English & German. I have installed & enabled all the necessary modules for Translation, and my content is also changing but **Menu titles are not translating**.

For eg: **Categories** is a **menu** and **category-1,category-2,...category-n** are the **sub-menu**s, so what I am getting is these sub menus are translating in German but **Category** title is not.